# Large Sampling with Replacement by index layer of a Pandas multiindexed Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sampling

Imagine a dataframe with the structure below:

```
>>> print(pair_df)

                                0         1
centre param h pair_ind                    
0      x1    1 (0, 1)    2.244282  2.343915
               (1, 2)    2.343915  2.442202
               (2, 3)    2.442202  2.538162
               (3, 4)    2.538162  2.630836
               (4, 5)    2.630836  2.719298
...                           ...       ...
9      x3    7 (1, 8)    1.407902  1.417398
               (2, 9)    1.407953  1.422860
             8 (0, 8)    1.407896  1.417398
               (1, 9)    1.407902  1.422860
             9 (0, 9)    1.407896  1.422860

[1350 rows x 2 columns]
```

What is the most efficient way to largely (e.g., 1000 times) sample (with replacement) this dataframe by index layer `centre` (10 values here) and put them all together?

I have found two solutions:

1)

```
import numpy as np

bootstrap_rand = np.random.choice(list(range(0,10)), size=len(range(0,10*1000)), replace=True).tolist()
sampled_df = pd.concat([pair_df.loc[idx[i, :, :, :], :] for i in bootstrap_rand])
```

2. 

```
sampled_df = pair_df.unstack(['param', 'h', 'pair_ind']).\
                     sample(10*1000, replace=True).\
                     stack(['param', 'h', 'pair_ind'])
```

Any more efficient ideas?

Comment: are all the other levels identical across the 10 centers?

Comment: @Ben.T not necessarily.